# Running Azure functions locally gives "No runtime" error after .NET7 upgrade

Tags: c#, .net, azure, visual-studio, function

Recently I wanted to upgrade my **Azure** functions to use **.NET 7**. For some reasons, after doing all the required steps, when I want to run any of the functions, I keep getting this error message box telling

> There is no Functions runtime available that matches the version
> project specified by the project

I checked to have the proper settings in the **.csproj** file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>$(MSBuildProjectName.Replace(" ", "_"))</RootNamespace>
    <_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>true</_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Yes, it is spelled with lowercase v for **"v4"**. I checked to have the hosting bundle for .NET7 installed according to my architecture (64-bit Windows) and I restarted the IIS Service after installation. I tried clean-rebuild, reopen Visual Studio, rebooting my compuer and nothing seems to be working. I also have the **.NET 7 SDK** installed and I am using **Visual Studio 2022**. If further info is needed, I will update my question accordingly. Thank you!

Answer (score 116, accepted):

I eventually found the solution for my case and I will post it here if anyone else faces it. As mentioned in a comment from [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/989) Github issue, I had to go to

> Tools -> Options -> Projects & Solutions -> Azure functions and click
> on the "Check for updates" button.

[image]

And then I had to download and install the pending updates.

[image]

This seems to have solved my issue. Hopefully this solution will help others too.

Comment: Thank you Gabriel for finding this. Do you happen to know how this "feature" was added? I understand using different versions of the runtime, but why aren't these "toolset and template" updates automatically included with the release of Visual Studio? Is the plan to add an "UPDATE" button that will be hidden somewhere in settings for every feature of the product going forward? Ideally, it would prompt you to select or install the correct runtime or just automatically work. Maybe it should be added as a nuget package? Should we try to let Microsoft know about this?

Comment: I had this problem with upgrading a dotnet-isolated azure functions project to net8.0. This solution solved it for me. I also updated some nuget packages referenced [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/ga-azure-functions-supports-net-8-in-the-isolated-worker-model/).

Comment: thank you for taking the time to post this information it resolved my issue also!

Comment: Well you saved me a couple hours of googling and forum posts. Take my upvote.

Comment: Sometimes I hate Microsoft! They make it seem so easy...