New Error Running Azure Function App Locally -- re Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions
Running our Azure Function App locally in Rider or VS 2022 has suddenly stopped working with the following error:
This version of the Azure Functions Core Tools requires your project to reference version 4.5.0 or later of Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions. Please update to the latest version.
We had been at v 4.0.1 and updated via Nuget to 4.5.  However we still cannot run the app.
From VS 2022 it pops up message:  There is no Functions runtime available that matches the version specified in the project.
From Rider, we get the same message as before:
This version of the Azure Functions Core Tools requires your project to reference version 4.5.0 or later of Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.
Any suggestions?
Thanks!
csproj file
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <AzureFunctionsVersion>V4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>true</_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
      <Compile Remove="ExpirationList.cs" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
        <PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.12.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph" Version="5.56.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph.Core" Version="3.1.12" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Client" Version="4.61.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.5.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Pdf.Net.Core" Version="26.2.5" />
        <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.XlsIO.Net.Core" Version="26.2.5" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <None Update="host.json">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </None>
        <None Update="local.settings.json">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
            <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        </None>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Include="..\Asap.Mgmt.WebApi.Data\Asap.Mgmt.WebApi.Data.csproj" />
      <ProjectReference Include="..\OidcApiAuthorization\OidcApiAuthorization.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>

===============
Sample function
public class AgendaApi
    {
        private readonly IApiAuthorization _apiAuthorization;
        private readonly IConfigurationRoot _config;
        UtilRepository _util;
        public AgendaApi(IApiAuthorization apiAuthorization)
        {
            _apiAuthorization = apiAuthorization;

            _config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();
            _util = new UtilRepository();
        }


        [FunctionName("GenerateAgenda2")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GenerateAgenda2(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "agenda/generateagenda2/hearing/{hearingid}")]
                    HttpRequest req, ILogger log, ExecutionContext context, int hearingid)
        {
            log.LogInformation("Reports - Generate Agenda 2");

            var repo = new AgendaRepository(_config, log, _util);
            var (fileContent, contentType) = await repo.GenerateAgenda2(hearingid);
            return new FileStreamResult(fileContent, contentType);
        }
    }
}


I should mention that the function app is .Net 6.0

Please share your .csproj file and function code

Hi Ikhtesam.  Thanks for your help.  Do you mean add an example of one api method?

I just ran into the same thing and this worked for me
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75146087/running-azure-functions-locally-gives-no-runtime-error-after-net7-upgrade

Please share your function code as well

Thanks Joshua Lee, but that did not fix the problem for me.


You should update the Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions library from NuGet up to 4.5.0

Then follow these instructions: https://itsallinthecode.com/fixing-there-is-no-functions-runtime-available-in-visual-studio.
You have to go to Tools > Options > Project and Solutions > Azure Functions > Click on "Check for updates" And when the "Download & Install" button appears, just click it, wait few seconds and relaunch the local functions, they should work



Attempted to upgrade the Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions to 4.5 but it didn't work for me. While it might work for some, this wasn’t feasible in my case, as other environments were running fine, and the issue was only occurring on my machine.
Here’s what worked for me:

Ensure that you have the .NET SDK 6.0 installed.
As suggested in this answer. Delete %LocalAppData%\AzureFunctionsTools and restart the VS. Note: It's crucial to have .NET 6.0 installed for this step to work.


The error is in your .csproj,
<AzureFunctionsVersion>V4</AzureFunctionsVersion>

You need to change your uppercase V to a lowercase v.
The uppercase V works with older functions...

This actually fixed the issue we had, thank you. Funny how this is a breaking change.

You need to update Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions specifically for the project.
Go into the folder of the functions project (Not the solution, but the actual project) and open a powershell window there.
Then run: dotnet add package Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions --version 4.5.0

Hi Wesley.  Thanks much.  I did as you suggested, and still get the popup:  "There is no Functions runtime available that matches the version specified in the project."

try changing local.settings.json
"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"

Update your Azure Functions toolsets and templates by going through menu to Tools>Options>Projects and Solutions>Azure Functions and then click Check for Updates button and update.
